# Convert TRX result file from VS 2015 (or later) loadtest to html

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2015, load-testing, webtest, trx

I'm struggling to proper convert the .trx result file from my **loadtest** (which contains .webtest) to HTML. I tried with **trx2html** (https://trx2html.codeplex.com/) but this is how it looks like with it (probably it was OK with non loadtest and older version of Visual Studio):
[image]

Then I tried with **trxer** (https://github.com/NivNavick/trxer) but once again most likely its not designed for loadtests so the result was like that:
[image]

Just for comparison this is how it looks like in Visual Studio 2015:
[image]
[image]

So my question is - Is there some other convertor out there which will do the job for loadtests and newer VS? My other option is to get some proper .xslt and convert the .trx (which is .xml) to proper .html.

Unfortunately I'm kind a lacking .xslt knowledge so it will be tough. Is there some .xslt that I can use for load/web tests? Maybe one from VS itself?

Comment: What do you expect in the output? You know that most of the load test results are held in the SQL database and very little is held in the trx file.

Comment: Good point. So to extract something like the test summary might be fine only from the trx, but graph like the one in Key Indicators will require also the SQL DB, right? If so it will became more complex (if its not run locally VSTS will provide this output with graphs out of the box). Did you perform such conversion and what output did you manage to get only from the trx?

Comment: The trx is just an xml file. Have a look at one with a text editor and see whether it contains what you want. The data for the graphs is in the database, not the trx.

Comment: All the data from "Load test summary" page is in the .trx file (xml) - mainly between <RunConfigurations> & <Summary> <PerformanceCounterResults>. Any suggestions how I can convert it to html to make it look similar to the one from VS?